# How can I check my solo mining hash rate?

Tags: hashrate

I need to find the command that lets me check my hash rate from monero-wallet-cli.  Further, what is considered a good hash rate?  I am running 2 threads.

Answer (score 3):

The daemon mines, the wallet does not. The command to start mining from the wallet is a convenience function, which merely asks the daemon to start mining, and there is no convenience function to ask for hash rate reporting.

In the daemon, you can check hash rate either with `show_hr` as Guest said, or `status`. `show_hr` will continuously log hash rate, while `status` is a one off.

When using the GUI wallet, the daemon hash rate is reported in the "Mining" tab.

Comment: thank you, it was really helpful to clarify some technical issues I had.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I assume you mining with the daemon (wallet) then
show_hr is the command